# Titanium Studio updates won't work

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

I can't use my titanium studio, because I can't successfully install the updates.

Here is the error log:

```
Error encountered during update
An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]com.appcelerator.titanium.feature.rcp_root 3.4.0.201409261227-827bFA2FF7cLVuUtuFNtX8GB189I --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
Backup of file /Applications/Titanium Studio/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.prefs failed.
File that was copied to backup could not be deleted: /Applications/Titanium Studio/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.prefs
```

Could someone help me out here, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have at least one update site checked in the Preferences Window.
Select the Window -> Preferences menu.
From there, Select the Install/Update -> Available Software Sites branch on the left.
Select the update site depending on your needs. (usually Titanium Studio Stable Updates) at URL http://download.appcelerator.com/appcelerator/studio/standalone/update/stable/
Re-try Update.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to update to 3.4.0 Beta? If so there might be problem arising in update. There is   an unresolved issue here, please take a look.
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-4667